# SQL | Join two tables and get one of the tables column against any of the matching row

Tags: sql, oracle, hana

Table A stores site-article wise transfer/transit stock.

Table A

```
    site     article     transfer_Stock     transit stock
    s1        a1            10                15
    s1        a2            20                25
```

Table B has site-article-storage location wise stock

Table B

```
    site     article     sloc     stock
    s1        a1         1000      5
    s1        a1         2000      10
    s1        a1         3000      15
    s1        a2         1000      20
    s1        a2         5000      25
```

I want to get total stock as for site article

Output required -

```
   site     article     sloc     transfer_stock    transit_stock    stock
   s1        a1         1000         10               15             5
   s1        a1         2000          0                0             10
   s1        a1         3000          0                0             15
   s1        a2         1000         20               25             20
   s1        a2         5000          0                0             25
```

I want transfer stock and transit stock against any of the row of sloc.

Table  A has 1 billion rows and Table B has 1.5 billion rows.

what is the optimised way to achieve this in sql.

Currently we are achieving this throguh

```
SELECT A.site, 
A.article, 
B.sloc, 
case when MIN_B.sloc=B.sloc then A.transfer_stock else 0 end as transfer_stock,
case when MIN_B.sloc=B.sloc then A.transit_stock else 0 end as transit_stock, 
B.stock
FROM A
LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON A.site = B.site AND A.article = B.article
LEFT OUTER JOIN (select site,article,min(sloc) from B group by site,article) MIN_B on A.site = MIN_B.site AND A.article = MIN_B.article
```

Comment: Please provide additional info on how to link your two tables. There are multiple ways to combine them into your expected output

Comment: Output will be at site article sloc level granularity. We can join them on site-article.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.site, A.article, B.sloc, A.transfer_stock, A.transit_stock, B.stock
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON A.site == B.site AND A.article == B.article;
```

Comment: this is simple left outer join. it will repeat transfer stock and transit stock against all storage locations.